# How can I get the values of non-NAN elements in a Matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a huge matrix for which I need the row, column and values of non-NAN elements.

This works when I have zero (instead of NAN) and non-zero elements:

```
[rwpRow, rwpCol, rwpVal] = find( zerotest )
```

But when I do this for NAN matrix, I get all 1 values.

```
[rwpRow, rwpCol, rwpVal] = find(~isnan(nantest))
```

How can I do this?

Comment: `find` returns you all 1s because that's what it is supposed to do. It returns all nonzero elements in `~isnan(nantest)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The input to `find` is a logical array which is 1 for all non-nan elements. That 1 is what you get and `find` does not "see" the actual values. You have to split that up into separate calls:

```
select=~isnan(nantest)
[rwpRow, rwpCol] = find(select)
rwpVal=nantest(select)
```

Comment: Thanks! Quick question: If I want to get the cellnumbers directly instead of Row, Cols, how would I go about it? I can calculate, but I wonder if there is a single line answer.

Comment: What are cellnumbers? Are you talking about linear indexing vs subscript indexing?

Comment: `[linear_index] = find(select)`

Comment: Thanks!! That's what I was looking for. When I try to subset using row/col, I get a n*n elements instead of just n. It will be easier with linear index. http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/02/08/linear-indexing/

Answer (score 0):

You can only get the rows and columns from the call to `find` since it finds the 1s in `~isnan(nantest)`. Get all the non NaN values in the matrix in another step:

```
[rwpRow, rwpCol] = find(~isnan(nantest));
vals = nantest(~isnan(nantest));
```